# Apache Artemis : Understanding max disk usage and address full policy

Tags: activemq-artemis

In Artemis there is global `max-disk-usage` parameter. Also in address settings we have `address-full-policy`. Below is my settings for those two.

```
<max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
-----
<address-full-policy>FAIL</address-full-policy>
```

My intention is when the disk usage reached 90%, i want producers to fail. But having reading documentation i skeptical that `address-full-policy` will stop the paging. Does it stop the paging ? Also when message reached server when it persisted ? Is it immediate ?

With testing i found that above setting fails the producers. If disk usage drop below 90% then is it still stop paging ?

Comment: Please use the `activemq-artemis` tag on your questions rather than the `artemis` tag. The `artemis` tag is for a completely unrelated software project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time the broker will page is if you use:

```
<address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
```

In other words, if you use:

```
<address-full-policy>FAIL</address-full-policy>
```

Then the broker will not page when the address reaches either `max-disk-usage` or `max-size-bytes`.